# How do I add a breakpoint to a JavaScriptCatalog view?

Tags: django, debugging, django-i18n

As per [the documentation for `JavaScriptCatalog`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n), I added the following lines to the `urlpatterns` in one of my Django apps:

```py
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r"^jsi18n/?", JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name="javascript-catalog"),
    # ...
]
```

But if I navigate to http://localhost/jsi18n, I see that it's not [loading the catalog](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fe9c7ded2996364f853c524b4421274717d89d5f/django/views/i18n.py#L111-L116):

```js
// ...
  /* gettext library */

  django.catalog = django.catalog || {};
  

  if (!django.jsi18n_initialized) {
// ...
```

How do I go about debugging this? How can I insert a `breakpoint()` into the `JavaScriptCatalog.as_view()` value to see what it's doing and where it's looking?

Comment: I think the title should change to *"how to add breakpoints to Django template"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass the original class, put a `breakpoint()` in its `__init__` and then call `super().__init__`:

```py
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog
from django.conf.urls import url


class MyCatalog(JavaScriptCatalog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        breakpoint()
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r"^jsi18n/?", MyCatalog.as_view(), name="javascript-catalog"),
    # ...
]
```

Or overwrite some other method, such as [`get_catalog`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fe9c7ded2996364f853c524b4421274717d89d5f/django/views/i18n.py#L264):

```py
class MyCatalog(JavaScriptCatalog):
    def get_catalog(self, *args, **kwargs):
        breakpoint()
        return super().get_catalog(*args, **kwargs)
```